# How to check if a path exists between two nodes of length exactly x in an undirected graph?

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

An undirected graph is given (as an adjacency list or incidence matrix). For multiple queries, check if a path of length exactly x exists between two nodes. Same nodes can be visited more than once.

I know that for single queries it's easy to check for this, simply by raising the incidence matrix to the power x (number of steps) and checking if the value at [first node][second node] is greater that 0. This takes too long, and for bigger matrices it takes too much memory. Even more so for multiple queries.

How can I solve this problem using as little space and time as possible?

---

Example:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8aIU.png)

Queries:

- Is it possible to reach 3 from 2 in 1 step? yes
- Is it possible to reach 4 from 1 in 1 step? no
- Is it possible to reach 5 from 5 in 8 steps? yes
- Is it possible to reach 8 from 1 in 10 steps? no

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any path or just simple paths?

Comment: @LiorKogan What do you mean by that? The problem is to check if ANY path exists between the two nodes that is of the given length.

Comment: In a simple path all vertices of the path be distinct.

Comment: @LiorKogan In this case, same nodes can be visited more than once